# How to ignore all blank form fields when updating a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { in: 6..255 }
end
```

... and a standard controller and view. The user form does not present the current password. I want to avoid this blank password being set on the model. I only want to update the password when it is non-blank.

I tried:

```
model_params = params.reject {|k, v| v == ""}
@model.update!(model_params)
```

But it did not work, can not be skip model validates.

When I call `model.update!` Rails reports:

> ```
> Validation failed:  Password can't be blank, Password is too short (minimum is 6 characters)
> ```

Comment: `params[:model].reject{ |k,v| v.blank? }` should remove every key/value pair where the value is blank. But I don't really understand "I don't how to merge `params` in `@model` before update in the database."

Comment: However, I just wanna skip validation when model update if the field is blank. @MrYoshiji

Comment: skipping validations is probably not what you should do (according to the example you gave with User's password). The key/value pair `params[:user][:password]` should be deleted of the hash if you do `params[:user].reject{ |k,v| v.blank? }` before update, therefore the validations will not run on `password` since it has not changed.

Comment: Yes. I did. and puts params check, the password key has removed. But Rails always says Validation failed. @MrYoshiji

Comment: Maybe the user(s) you are trying to test have no password at all in the first place?

Comment: I'm sure the user has password. btw, the password is virtual key(has_secure_password), the real key is password_digest. @MrYoshiji

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I take either of the 2 approaches (in order):

First, Adding `:if` condition to validation:

```
validates :password, 
    presence: true, 
    length: { in: 6..255 },
    if: lambda { new_record? || !password.blank? }
```

Second, Running this validation on `create` only

```
validates :password, 
    presence: true, 
    length: { in: 6..255 },
    on: create
```

HTH

Comment: thank you very much, it's work! and I think the first case better.

Comment: I think the first case is better too, because the second one allows you to create a new record with an empty password by doing `user = User.new` then `user.save`

Answer (score 1):

You can just add ! to reject like this,

```
model_params = params.reject! {|k, v| v == ""}
@model.update!(model_params)
```

Answer (score -1):

try to modify the migration file of your model , so that the fields you want to leave blank wont be problem in the database for example :

```
create_table(:users) do |t|

  t.string :email,              null: true, default: ""
  t.string :encrypted_password, null: true, default: ""
end
```

then you should

```
rake db:migrate
```

if the table is already created try to run a change_column migration

Comment: you're welcome, please enlighten me more so that I see if I can help